# Detect if a computer is a NetApp filer? (Unmanaged C++)

Tags: c++, netapp

What is the best way to detect if a computer on a network is a netapp filer? I have tried some general querying of the computers attributes, but nothing has stuck out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) is enabled by default on filers ( though it may later be disabled ). Info on the available MIB can be found [here](http://communities.netapp.com/docs/DOC-1075).